# AppBar title with image flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, appbar

I have the attached AppBar and I want to add an image next to the title, not in action Icon, only image, how can I handle this?

```dart
appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Title'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              new IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.refresh),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(
                    () {
                      widget.athkarCategory.reset();
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

[image]

Comment: you want the image to be actionable?

Comment: Use `Row` as widget for title. To get your desired layout, pass `Text` and `Image` widgets to `Row` as children.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `title` property of the `AppBar` accepts a `Widget`, which means any combination of them.

So for instance, if you want an image next to the title you can simply wrap it in a `Row` widget and then add the `Image` next to the `Text` which will contain your title.

Here a code example of what you are trying to accomplish: https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b

The relevant code parts are this:

```dart
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(widget.title),
            Image.network("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Uk1RPEQI8mI/maxresdefault.jpg", width: 50, height:50)
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I want

Comment: @Huda You also want to add `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center` in `Row` if you want to center aligned.

Answer (score 1):

AppBar title takes a widget. So you can customise the app bar title the way you want.

Example:

```dart
AppBar(
        title: Container(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Title With Image'),
              Icon(Icons.refresh),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
AppBar(
    leading: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.arrow_back,
        color: Color(0xff6D6E70),
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
    ),
    title: Row(children: <Widget> [
          Text(
      "Title".toUpperCase(),
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Color(0xff6D6E70),
      ),
    ),
      Icon(Icons.save),
    ]),
    actions: <Widget>[
      Center(
        child: Wrap(
          spacing: 4,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
             Icons.satellite, //Refresh Icon
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.5),
              child: Text(
                "25",
              ),
            ) //This container is to add further text like showing an icon and then showing test
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `leading`

```
     AppBar(leading: IconButton(
         icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
         iconSize: 20.0,
         onPressed: () { 
            //you can call a function here
                      }),
                    centerTitle: true,
                    title: Text("Your title"),)
```